# Reactjs Input Upload doesn't return local URL

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mdbreact

I have a problem when trying to display image preview before upload it to server. I 'm using reactjs.

My problem is when I try to upload an image I got the file data but when I'm using reader, it doesn't return local URL and just show `undefined`

this is the topic that I tried to follow [get-image-preview-before-uploading-in-react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38049966/get-image-preview-before-uploading-in-react)

but when I try to check my image local url it return `undefined`

this is what I import in my file:

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import { MDBContainer, MDBRow, MDBCol, MDBBtn, MDBIcon, MDBInput, MDBDropdown, MDBDropdownToggle, MDBDropdownMenu, MDBDropdownItem  } from 'mdbreact';
```

this is my js:

```
<p className="text-upload">Front Desain</p>
<input ref="file" type="file" name="front Design" onChange={this.frontDesign}/>
```

this is my method or function:

```
  frontDesign = (e) =>{
    var file = this.refs.file.files[0];
    var reader = new FileReader();
    var url = reader.readAsDataURL(file);

    reader.onloadend = function (e) {
        this.setState({
          form:{
            frontDesign: [reader.result]
          }
        })
      }.bind(this);
    console.log("Check Data : ", file)
    console.log("Check URL : ", url)

  }
```

and this is my state:

```
  state ={
    form:{
      frontDesign: [],
    }
  }
```

this is my console:
[image: What I got in my Console]

This my codesandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-mclaren-zb1l7?fontsize=14

can someone help me to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[From the mozilla website](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL) it seams you need to add a load event listener to your reader. This sample code is not supported in some versions of IE.

```
...

reader.addEventListener("load", () => {
  this.setState(state => ({
    ...state,
    form:{
      frontDesign: [reader.result]
    }
  }))
  const url = reader.result;
  console.log(url);
}, false);

...
```

Working condeSanbox here: https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-lamport-dnbij

Comment: thankyou for the answer, I try to use this approach but when I use `console.log("Check URL : ", url)` to check it, it still return undefined

Comment: as for the fileReader, I always use it like this but in fact I don't really know how to use another approach for this file upload

Comment: That's weird can you add a CodeSandbox  link?, it might be the `react ref`  try passing the id of your input to your onChange method and use `document.getElementById` or use @Cong anwser

Comment: I tried @Cong answer but it return another error, wait I'll try to make something to try

Comment: @RakisFriski, I think you might need to add load event listener to your reader. Please create a codesandbox it will easier to help.

Comment: I'll already make it in https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-mclaren-zb1l7?fontsize=14

Comment: @RakisFriski check this out : https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-lamport-dnbij

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198074/discussion-between-morlo-mbakop-and-rakis-friski).

Answer (score 1):

Do not need use ref here. Try to code below

```
frontDesign = (e) => {
  var file = e.target.files[0];
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = (e) => {
    //Image URL e.target.result
    this.setState({
      form:{
        frontDesign: [e.target.result]
      }
    })
  }
  reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}
```

Comment: Thankyou for the answer, but when i try to use this I got  another error that said ` Failed to execute 'readAsDataURL' on 'FileReader': The object is already busy reading Blobs.`